# Who is Silas Ramsbottom based on?

Tags: character, identify-this-actor, despicable-me-2

The figure of Silas Ramsbottom in *Despicable Me 2* looks like a British actor.

Look at the top half of his face, the bottom is too exaggerated. The resemblance is strongest when he lifts his eyebrows unevenly as in the second picture.

I am thinking of a spy movie... But I am unable to find who. Does anyone recognize the real life person?

[edited] Note: I'm not talking about the voice, but the ways he looks. It's not [Gary Oldman in Tinker Tailor Soldier Spy](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1206&bih=891&q=gary+oldman+tinker+tailor+soldier+spy&oq=gary+oldman+tinker+tailor+soldier+spy)

[image: Silas Ramsbottom]
[image: Silas Ramsbottom]

Comment: I too thought Silas Ramsbottom reminded me of a British actor. Silas Ramsbottom reminds me of Robert Morley. The character certainly acts and sounds like Morley.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Answering my own question). [Lam's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/41342/20086) helped me find him: it is [James Fox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Fox)

[image]
[image]
[image]

[Many other people have noted the resemblance](https://www.google.com/search?q=silas+ramsbottom+edward+fox) but I could not find an authoritative source.

Not surprisingly Silas also somewhat resembles Edward Fox, [since they are brothers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_Fox_family).

Comment: He definatly resembles James Fox.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly English actor [Edward Fox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Fox_%28actor%29) or his brother, actor [James Fox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Fox).

Edward:

[image]

James:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer and give an explanation for why Edward Fox or his brother fits.

Answer (score -1):

Since the new movie coming and Silas Ramsbottom is back, that character immediately reminded me of actor Robert Morley, didn't know his name before.

Comment: Not a bad match either, but I assume Silas would've had less hair then.